# TypeError: b.dataAdapter is null select2: jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 $('.fld_inp_slt, .fld_inp_sltList, .inp_select').on("change", function (event) {
    //* Check the size of select drop down, if more than certain size then only attach the filtering select2
    var selectSize = $(this).children('option').length;

    if (selectSize > 10)
    {
        $(this).select2();
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).select2({minimumResultsForSearch: -1});
    }

    $(this).hide(); //hide the select element as the dropdown will be handled by the select2
});
```

i am doing together with ajax stuff, let say i got a drop-down box, whenever i select something in the drop-down box, then the next drop-down box will appear the child of what i select (using ajax and js to push in the options to drop-down box), the jquery code above is to check if the options is more than 10 then will call select2 to refresh and appear the search bar for me, but i got the error *TypeError: b.dataAdapter is null*